# Can't save a OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship in Spring Data REST request

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Data JPA and Spring Data Rest.
When making a REST request to persist an entity, I get the next error:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value
```

My data model has the following entities:

Contract:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Contract implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy="contract"
    )
    private List<Participation> participants = new ArrayList<Participation>();

    private String name;

}
```

Participation:

```
@Entity
public class Participation implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
        
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false) //By default the column will be CONTRACT_ID
    private Contract contract;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Contact contact;

    private String clauses;
}
```

Contact:

```
@Entity
public class Contact implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String emailAddress;
}
```

I have 2 JPARepositories:

```
public interface ContractRepository extends JpaRepository<Contract, Long> {
    List<Contract> findByNameContainsIgnoreCase(String name);
}

public interface ContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, Long> {
}
```

To save a new Contract with a couple of participations, I am doing the next steps in Postman:

1. Create a Contract and get its href:

Request: POST http://localhost:8080/api/contracts

Body:

```
{
   "name": "Contract1"
}
```

The response is successful:

```
201 Created
{
  "name": "Contract1",
  "participants": [],
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/contracts/4"
    },
    "contract": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/contracts/4"
    },
  }
}
```

2. So far so good. Now that I have the contract persisted, I am adding participants:
   Contact 1 already exists in the data base.

Request: PATCH http://localhost:8080/api/contracts/4

Body:

```
{
    "participants": [
        {
            "clauses": "Bla bla bla",
            "contact": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/contacts/1"
            },
            "contract": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/contracts/4"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When executing this request the system complains on the field/fk contract:

```
{
    "cause": {
        "cause": null,
        "message": "not-null property references a null or transient value : com.xxx.xxx.model.Participation.contract"
    },
    "message": "not-null property references a null or transient value : com.xxx.xxx.model.Participation.contract; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.xxx.xxx.model.Participation.contract"
}
```

I tried several ways to reference the contract in the participation, like:

```
"contract": "http://localhost:8080/api/contracts/4"
```

No luck. For some reason the system is leaving the field empty instead of using the foreing key of the entity created in step 1.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use DTOs instead of entities to be sent with json

Comment: I am probably going to do that since it is a good practice to have a layer of DTOs between the exposed API and the Persistence tier. Well, at least for projects with a reasonable complexity degree. Though, I would like to know how to do this if I keep this approach and use the API exposed automatically by the framework (Spring Data REST) based on the JPA repositories created. It surely has a way to manage this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by:

1. Add a new repository ParticipationRepository (extends JpaRepository);
2. Create first a Contract without Participations:

> POST http://localhost:8080/api/contracts {    "name": "Contract1" }

Response:

```
201 Created
{
  "name": "Contract1",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/contracts/3"
    },
    "contract": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/contracts/3"
    },
    "participants": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/contracts/3/participants"
    }
  }
}
```

3. Create a Participation and use the URI from the just created Contract to set the FK. Assume Contact 1 already exists in the Data Base.

> POST http://localhost:8080/api/participations {
> "clauses": "bla, bla, bla",
> "contract": "http://localhost:8080/api/contracts/3",
> "contact": "http://localhost:8080/api/contacts/1" }

Response:

```
201 Created
{
  "clauses": "bla, bla, bla",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/participations/5"
    },
    "participation": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/participations/5"
    },
    "contract": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/participations/5/contract"
    },
    "contact": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/contacts/5/contact"
    }
  }
}
```